# How much does having Aero on affect battery life?

Tags: windows-7, battery-life, aero

Just started using Windows 7. Aero makes thing look pretty but it doesn't have any pragmatic purpose does it?

I was wondering though, I haven't noticed a performance effect, but does Aero have a noticable effect on battery life?

Just wondering whether I should turn it off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In our testing we've seen that turning on Aero consumes only about **1-4% more** of battery life.  In terms of making your battery last longer, turning off Aero will not go very far while at the same time costing you some of the cool features that make Windows Vista fun to use, such as Flip 3D, taskbar previews, window transparency and so on.

Taken from [here](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/archive/b/windowsvista/archive/2007/05/14/aero-and-battery-life.aspx)

Comment: Not only cool and fun, taskbar preview actually made me works faster!

Comment: It's one of the best features of Windows 7 (imho)

Answer (score 0):

I've found from personal experience that it doesn't have any more affect than running Windows Media Player or streaming something on a website. There's some more info about what you can do with Aero here, if you're interested: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/aero.aspx